# Java Spring: Método post não insere o id do relacionamento

Tags: java, spring

Estou aprendendo o framework Spring, tentei seguir alguns tutoriais de relacionamento 1-1 onde uma biblioteca possui um endereço. Ao enviar no body os dados da biblioteca e o id do endereço, um novo registro é inserido na tabela bibliotecas, porém o `address_id` que referencia um endereço não é inserido, mesmo passando no request payload.

Meu model **Library**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Bibliotecas")
public class Library implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  private String name;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Address address;

  public Library() {
  }

  public long getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Address getAddress() {
    return this.address;
  }

  public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
  }

}
```

Meu model **Address**:

```
@Entity
public class Address {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String location;

  public long getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getLocation() {
    return this.location;
  }

  public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
  }

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  private Library library;

}
```

Meus **repositories**:

```
public interface LibraryRepository extends JpaRepository<Library, Long> {}
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long> {}
```

Meu library **resource**:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class LibraryResource {

  @Autowired
  LibraryRepository libraryRepository;

  @GetMapping("/libraries")
  public List<Library> listaBibliotecas() {
    return libraryRepository.findAll();
  }

  @PostMapping("/library")
  public Library salvaBiblioteca(@RequestBody Library library) {
    return libraryRepository.save(library);
  }
}
```

E então eu passo no meu request:

```
{
    "name": "Biblioteca test",
    "address_id": 1
}
```

Obs: Existe um address com `id` 1, eu recebo de retorno:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Biblioteca test",
    "address": null
}
```

No meu retorno address é null, e quando dou um select no banco, o registro criado possui address_id null. Como posso corrigir a ligação entre esses dois modelos? Porque isso está ocorrendo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua request deveria ser assim.

Montei um exemplo aqui no [Github](https://github.com/rafaelchagasb/answers-stackoverflow/tree/master/pt.stackoverflow.com/spring-java/452498) com base nas suas classes.

```
{
    "name": "Biblioteca test",
    "address": {
        "id":"1" 
    }
}
```

Response

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Funcionou dessa forma, @rafaelchagasb, obrigado. Você sabe me dizer porque o location retorna null mesmo quando o registro relacionado possui dados na coluna location?

Comment: O save não irá retornar o objeto do seu relacionamento de forma gerenciada. ELe irá retornar os dados que você enviar para ele. 

Nesse caso aqui, ele irá tentar fazer o relacionamento com o adress de id 1 e irá retornar o objeto com as demais propriedades que você enviou.
 
{
    "name": "Biblioteca test",
    "address": {
     "id":"1",
     "location": "objeto"
    }
}

Talvez se você trocar o método sabe pelo merge resolva o problema ou você teria que realizar a consulta do objeto library para ele retornar todos os dados.